# How integrate phirehose lib to symfony2?

Tags: symfony, phirehose

I`m writing app that should work with twitter streaming api. For interacting with streaming api I use phirehose lib (https://github.com/fennb/phirehose). It runs great as separate php project. Php file with Phirehose lib is used as background process, that constantly consumes tweets, now I want save it in Db, so I need somehow make available all advantages work with DB of symfony framework in my simple php file that consumes tweets. Is there a way to make this, except put phirehose in vendor folder of symfony (I don't want to do this, cause in manuals that I find it is not easy, rename file and classes of lib, which can cause problems inside lib)?

Answer (score 0):

This library is simple to use with composer. Just have a look at the [composer.json](https://github.com/fennb/phirehose/blob/master/composer.json) file.

Add the following to your symfony composer.json then run `composer update`

```
"fennb/phirehose": "dev-master"
```

When extending the phirehose classes just do

```
class TwitterStuff extends \Phirehose
{
   .........
```

Comment: I install Symfony just download archive, so should I install it once again using composer? I just has no composer.json file in root dir of symfony, so I don't know where should I add these strings.

Comment: Composer will handle the autoloading and downloading of the library. Add the first code example to your symfony composer.json. It will be much more convenient long term than downloading it yourself.